# Make client point to DC for DNS automatically

Tags: dns, windows-server-2003, server-configuration, windows-networking

I couldn´t find a specific answer for my question so here it goes: We have a local network with 5 computers and a server running Windows Server 2003. The network was working properly but it seems that the server rebooted and we had to give a static DNS address to each workstation, otherwise they connect to the router 192.168.1.1 and are unable to access the local network or the Internet. 
So my question is, how do you set up the server so that each workstation uses the server´s IP as primary DNS automatically? Or is it better to configure each client with a static DNS?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: As far as I know as long as the server is running the DHCP service then the server should assign the IP's to all connected computers?

Comment: That's right, the IPs seem to be properly assigned, the problem is that if I set each client to obtain a DNS automatically they use the router's IP and they can't connect to the network.

Comment: If you are using the DHCP service on the server make sure that DHCP is disabled on the router?

Comment: No, could that be the problem? Let me tell you the setup: There is a router (192.168.1.1) and a gateway (192.168.0.254) connected to it, they both have DHCP enabled. The server has a static IP 192.168.0.2, is using the gateway as the "default gateway" and points to its own private IP for DNS. Should the settings be different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, open services (WIndows Key + R, services.msc, Hit enter) and check that 'DHCP Server' is running and set to automatic, if not, right click and select start. While your there restart the DNS Server service.

Secondly, if you are still getting your Router's DNS, log in to your router and ensure DHCP is disabled - you router may have been reset and this may have enabled DHCP which is causing all these problems.

Third, Open DHCP (Start > Administrative Tools > DHCP), Expand your server, you should then see a folder with 'scope' in the name, if not your DHCP needs to be configured (last resort), expand the scope, then select Scope options, it is in this that you will see the IP address of the '006 DNS server'. If it is missing, right click and select configure options, scoroll down to 006 DNS Servers and enter the name or (preferably) the IP address of your DNS server.

I'm 90% sure it'll be your router was reset.

I also thoroughly recommend you migrate from your Server 2003 machine to a new OS and new hardware if it is older than 4 years old as Server 2003 reached end of life on 08/04/2014 along with Windows XP and Office 2003.

Lastly, this may be more suited to ServerFault rather than StackOverflow (same family of websites)

Comment: Thank you so much, it seems that the router was reset and the DHCP service was not running on the server, however, we decided to use static IPs for the computers we have, since we only have five and there are some primters that seem to work better with a static address. Anyway, thanks for the suggestions and sorry for not using ServerFault, didn´t know about it.

Comment: Good to hear you got to the bottom of it.